# Do older versions of javascript evaluate ("-1" < 0) as false?

Tags: javascript

A bit of js on my brother's eCommerce site computes and stores transaction totals every time someone checks out. Periodically, a negative value is stored for tracker_total_amount. While he tries to work out why, he's decided to hard code an override which should address the ~0.1% of transactions with nonsensical values. It looks like this:

```
var tracker_total_amount = parseFloat(tracker.total_amount).toFixed(2);
    if(tracker_total_amount < 0){
        tracker_total_amount = 0;
    }
```

Negative values have continued to show up in the system.

Original theory:

I don't think he should be using .toFixed, because that's going to cast tracker_total_amount as a string - which, in my mind, would have stopped the if < 0 condition working as expected. I was quite happy with this explanation until I tested it and the override worked. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/yXTrz/

New theory:

Different users are running different versions of javascript. Some very small subset use an ancient version of javascript which (instead of helpfully converting the string to a float like mine is doing) continue to treat it as a string and always evaluate tracker_total_amount as being > 0, preventing the override from firing.

Question:

Did older version of javascript behave in this way? Could some users still be running those old versions? Best of all - is there a way I can simulate legacy versions of javascript to prove my theory?

Edit: I should point out all the important stuff (payment etc) relies on a server side calculated value. The numbers here are just what's stored in Google Analytics afterwards, so - while it's possible to manipulate - the results wouldn't be too atrocious.

Comment: I highly doubt it. If negative values are continuing, you have issues elsewhere or a rounding issue. Also note that this is not NaN friendly, although if you get NaNs, something is very wrong.

Comment: I read that the Yeti Browser does support testing of different Javascript implementations, not sure tho: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/08/25/introducing-yeti-the-yui-easy-testing-interface/

Comment: Here are two more theories: 1. some user is bypassing your JS validaton - there are numerous ways to do that, intentional or not. 2. there is a number which `parseFloat` parses differently from the server (NaN < 0 evaluates to false).

Comment: Might be a stretch, but it sounds like hackers trying to find eCommerce systems that allow for negative dollar amounts during checkout.

Comment: Additionally to Levi's comment, be sure you validate all money workflows serverside and double check for real valid amounts.

Comment: Wait, are you relying on the javascript to calculate how much the customer owes? If that's the case then yeah, your site is asking for trouble. Everything on the client side can be bypassed and replaced with any number the client wants. Never trust it.

Comment: Maybe they forbid javascript, and your code do nothing?I prefer things like so rather than javascript type conversion issue.

Comment: As @DanFromGermany says, server-side validation is necessary, otherwise, anybody can post a negative number by simulating a HTTP request.

Comment: The actual payment totals etc are all processed and calculated server side, it's just the tracking (and attempted tracking override) that are happening in javascript. Long term it'll all be server side but I'm temporarily perplexed by this js tangent in the meantime.

Comment: @mcl Remove `.toFixed` part (or use it later) and you won't have to worry about it. However most likely there is an error somewhere else.

Comment: The difference between `tracker.total_amount` and `tracker_total_amount` is just a single character; could it be possible that there's a typo and that the final tracking still uses the old value?

Answer (score 2):

You can get very small negative values to pass through, ie -0.001 because the value is being set to fixed. Not sure what kind of negatives you are seeing, but anything that goes outside of the fixed value as a negative will allow the negative through. Sorry, should be more clear, if there are further calculations that do not use the returned value and not the original value... The returned value would be -0.00... So if this is just being used as a test...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if older versions of Javascript are handling a string representation of your number differently or not, but you should be able to get around the problem by just using `toFixed()` after you check if the number is in range:

```
var tracker_total_amount = parseFloat(tracker.total_amount);
if (tracker_total_amount < 0) {
    tracker_total_amount = 0;
}
tracker_total_amount = tracker_total_amount.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

- About the 'why' : @Kevin's answer is correct, you can check it on the very code you linked to.
- About the 'how to fix it' : @Nerdwood's answer is great. Do all computations in numeric types (with rounding as expected), and only convert at boundaries.

But I'd like to add two points to be checked :

- Make sure your JS code is properly versionned, so that client browsers don't fetch a cached version without the "fix".
- Make sure this field isn't set or updated elsewhere.